# C Program Function

Tags: c, function, geometry

I don't want an answer in the form of code, but I do need to know how to start working on this problem.  I have just begun learning C language and during the learning process, I am stuck with this confusing question. The question is as follows:

> Write a function to compute the distance between two points and use it to develop another function that will compute the area of the triangle whose vertices are ****A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2),*** and **C(x3,y3).*** Use these functions to develop a function which returns the value 1 if the point **(x,y)** lines inside the triangle ABC, otherwise returns a value 0.

Please suggest me the appropriate coding for this problem in C language and kindly include comments for better understanding.

**I know both the formulas by the way.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. We don't generally write programs to order.  We will help you debug an honest attempt to produce an answer.  Do you know the formulae you need to compute the distance between two points? The area of a triangle given the 3 sides?  Etc?

Comment: I am not in the business of writing your homework. You gain nothing if I did that. So why not have a bash and come back with that code and then I am prepared to help you

Comment: Usually new programmers just need a place to start.  I don't like the hateful comments above.  They show no understanding of what it takes to get started.  **Don't give answers, give directions.**

Answer (score 4):

Approach this problem, like all other coding problems, in increments.  Your problem statement states pretty much what you need to do:

first, write a routine to compute the distance between two points.  You need to find the formula to do this.  Probably easiest to use `double` variables, be sure to read about how to specify the format statement for `printf` so that it can print double variables.

next, find the formula to use in order to compute the area of a triangle.

the last step is the hardest, and you will need to use everything you learned in steps one and two.  Again, dig out your calculus or algebra book and see how this is done and then write code to do the same thing.  It is interesting to see how a math description gets translated to computer code, **they are not the same thing** and unless you write a lot comments in your code it will be difficult to see how they do the same function.

good luck.

PS. when defining a function that returns a double variable, code:

```
double distance_calc(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
{
   double computed_value;
   // do the formula and compute: computed_value = etc.
   return computed_value;
}
```

Hope this helps.